# Dockerfile environment variables snafoo

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN mkdir -p ./webpieces
COPY . ./webpieces/
COPY config/logback.cloudrun.xml ./webpieces/config/logback.xml
ENV PORT=8080
WORKDIR "/webpieces"
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/authservice", "-http.port=:$PORT", "-hibernate.persistenceunit=production"]
```

however, the string $PORT ends up in my application rather than 8080.  I also tried command line to no avail either.  any idea what is going on here?

I mean I run my application with

```
docker run --env PORT=8080 -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 gcr.io/orderly-gcp/authservice
```

and in startup it says

```
-http.port following usages:
    (optional, default: :8080)Http host&port.  syntax: {host}:{port} or just :{port} to bind to all NIC ips on that host
            Value Parsed::$PORT foundKey:true foundValue:true
```

The Value Parsed part usually will say :8080 if I am binding to all ports. It works fine if I hardcode to :8080 instead of :$PORT or :${PORT}.  I can't see to get variables to work.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following DockerFile:

```
from ubuntu

ENV PORT=8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/echo", "$PORT"]
```

This will print out '$PORT' because environment variables are not expanded when using the array ENTRYPOINT syntax. You can instead use the non-array syntax like so:

```
from ubuntu

ENV PORT=8080

ENTRYPOINT /bin/echo $PORT
```

This prints out '8080'.

Comment: omg, awesome!!!  Also, does the command line PORT from docker run override the ENV PORT or no?  I wasn't sure on that one.  I guess I can run it and see but I am not that confident in that I may be doing it wrong :( so thought I would ask just in case.

Comment: I've tested it and it looks like the command line environment variables do override variables declared with ENV syntax. You can find more information about variable precedence [here.](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/7236) According to that issue Dockerfile has the lowest precedence where variables defined via Docker Compose have the most.